# Show that $C \subseteq Y$ is connected if and only if $f^{-1}(C)$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

- Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous open surjection such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is
  connected for each $y \in Y .$ Show that $C \subset Y$ is connected if and only if
  $f^{-1}(C)$ is connected.

  $(\Leftarrow)$ Assume $f^{-1}(C)$ is connected and $C\subseteq Y$ is disconnected, that is there are $U_1,U_2\in Y$ such that $C\subseteq U_1\cup U_2$, $C\cap U_1\neq \emptyset$ and $C\cap U_2\neq \emptyset.$ Then $f^{-1}(C)\subseteq f^{-1}(U_1)\cup f^{-1}(U_2)$. $f^{-1}\left(U_{i}\right) \cap f^{-1}(C)$ are non-empty and disjoint (check this).  $f^{-1}(U_1)$ and $f^{-1}(U_2)$ are open in $X$ because $f$ is continuous, and nonempty because $f$ is surjective. Therefore, they form a separation of $f^{-1}(C)$, contradicting the assumption that $f^{-1}(C).$

**May you check my attempt? And may you help other case?** Thanks...

Comment: It is $U_i \subset Y$. The statements $C \cap U_i \neq \emptyset$ are part of the requirement (given by the definition of being disconnected and the subspace topology) so don’t write a “then” just beforehand. You contradict the assumption that $f^{-1}(C)$ is connected. For the other direction, just notice $C=f(f^{-1}(C))$.

Comment: @Mindlack Okey edited. Thanks...

Comment: I forgot the most important part: the request that $U_1 \cap U_2 \cap C$ be empty (for $U_1 \cap C$, $U_2 \cap C$ to be a partition of $C$ in open subsets). You have to check as well that the $f^{-1}(U_i) \cap f^{-1}(C)$ are non-empty and disjoint.

Comment: You can replace open by quotient s as nd it’s still true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f^{-1}[C]$ is connected, so is $C=f[f^{-1}[C]]$ by continuity (and surjectivity) of $f$. Note that that's much shorter than your failed attempt.

If we assume $C\subseteq Y$ is connected, assume for a contradiction that $O_1, O_2 \subseteq X$ are open subsets of $X$ that witness the disconnectedness of $f^{-1}[C]$: $$f^{-1}[C]\subseteq O_1 \cup O_2 \text{ and } O_1 \cap f^{-1}[C]\neq \emptyset \text{ and } O_2 \cap f^{-1}[C]\neq \emptyset \text{ and } O_1 \cap O_2 \cap f^{-1}[C]=\emptyset$$

(Note that you need that last intersection to be empty, otherwise almost any set would be disconnected!)

Now note $f[O_1], f[O_2]$ are open in $Y$ and that $C \subseteq f[O_1] \cup f_[O_2]$ (find a preimage for some $c \in C$, so $c \in X$ with $f(c')=c$; This $c' \in f^{-1}[C]$ so is in $O_1$ or $O_2$ and so its $f$-image $c$ is in one of the $f[O_i]$ as well).

$f(c') \in C \cap f[O_1]$ for any $c' \in O_1 \cap f^{-1}[C]$ and similarly we see that $f[O_2] \cap C\neq \emptyset$.

If however $c \in C \cap f[O_1] \cap f[O_2]$ existed we see that $F_c:=f^{-1}[\{f(c)\}]$ would be non-empty and $O_1$ and $O_2$ would witness the disconnectedness of $F_c$, which cannot happen by assumption. So $C \cap f[O_1] \cap f[O_2] = \emptyset$ and all the previous would imply $C$ is not connected, contradiction. So $f^{-1}[C]$ must be connected when $C$ is.

Note that the proof can easily be adapted to closed (continuous onto) maps as well, and with a bit more care to hereditarily quotient maps (or restricted to $Y$ connected implies $X$ connected and just an onto quotient map).

Comment: Thanks for answer.